# Initializing a big array of a certain structure -- getting seg faults

Tags: c, memoization

The following code is giving me a seg fault. gdb says its coming from the line `memos[j][k] -> cost = -1;`, but I can't tell exactly what is wrong. I'm guessing something with how I am allocating memory and that the array index is mistakenly out of bounds?

```
memo_array_t mk_empty_memo_array(int l) {

    int n = pow(2, l+2);
    memo_t **memos = (memo_t **) malloc(n*sizeof(struct memo_s));
    for(int i = 0; i < pow(2, l+2); i++) {
        memos[i] = (memo_t *) malloc(n*sizeof(struct memo_s *));
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < pow(2, l+2); k++) {
            memos[j][k] -> cost = -1;
            memos[j][k] -> color = -1;
            memos[j][k] -> split = -1;
            memos[j][k] -> box = NULL; 
            memos[j][k] -> split_value = -1; 
        }
    }

    memo_array_t memo_array = (memo_array_t) malloc(sizeof(struct memo_array_s));
    memo_array -> dim = n;
    memo_array -> memos = memos;

    return memo_array;
}
```

In case you want to see the struct typedefs:

```
typedef struct memo_s {
  int cost;
  int color;
  int split;
  double split_value;
  box_t box;  
} *memo_t;

typedef struct memo_array_s {
  int dim;
  memo_t **memos;
} *memo_array_t;
```

Comment: First of all, [don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858). Then you're mixing the types for the `sizeof` operator in your two calls. The first call allocates an array of *pointers* and the second an array of *values*. Or rather, the first call should use a double-pointer to the structure, or a pointer to `memo_t` as operand to the `sizeof` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
memo_t **memos = malloc(n*sizeof(struct memo_s **));
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {                // ^^ two *s here!
    memos[i] = malloc(n*sizeof(struct memo_s *));   

    // And finally, allocate the actual structs:  
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {    
        memos[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(struct memo_s); 
    }
}
```

So the first `malloc` allocates an array of pointers to pointers, the second `malloc` allocates an array of pointers, and the third `malloc` (which you were missing) allocates space for the actual structs (since you had a 2D array of *pointers*, not a 2D array of *structs*).

Also, [don't cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/3425536). And in the loop condition, use the value of `n` you calculated instead of calculating it again.

I think it would be simpler to have just one name for the struct and then add a `*` after the name to make it a pointer, instead of having `memo_s` be the actual struct and `memo_t` being a pointer to that struct. I found it really confusing while trying to fix this.

Comment: Ok, I made the suggested changes. Unfortunately, I still receive the same error (segfault at the memos[x][y] -> cost = -1). I fixed the casting problem too.

Comment: Wait a sec I'm not done with all your errors yet... I'll edit the answer soon. Check Joachim's answer meanwhile.

Answer (score 1):

Besides your allocations of the arrays being (partly) wrong, the problem is that you don't allocate the actual structures. `memo[j][k]` is a pointer, but you don't make it point anywhere so when you dereference it you have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: I guess I'm confused by your suggestion -- it seems like the first for loop in my code is allocating space for memo[j][k]

Comment: @Craig You have, in a way, an array of arrays of pointers. You allocate the outer and inner array, but not the contained pointer. See the answer from Zenith.